# run a debug mode through command line in Maven android project

Tags: android, maven

I have a question that I want to debug(not Run) my Android project with Maven, How it will attached with debugger through command line with Maven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter how a process is started on the device or emulator, you can attach the debugger to any running process. From the devices view just select the process you want to debug and click on the little green bug.

Comment: This is nor right. Only apk which was builded as debuggable allow attach the debugger. No other process will be visible in devices tab in Eclipse. Only exception is rooted android compiled itself in debug mode. It will allow debug all process.

Answer (score 1):

I found that only way how to now force maven to compile apk in debug mode is this

```
  <aaptExtraArgs><aaptExtraArg>--debug-mode</aaptExtraArg></aaptExtraArgs>
```

in  of com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2 plugin

So. You can add this by default to pom.xml and create  with name 'release' that will turn it off and sign it by production key.

I added request to the better support of enable debug mode:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/issues/detail?id=257